# Endorsement from multiple peers one arg

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a multiple peer, one org Org1MSP network where I want the transactions to be endorsed by multiple peers.

Is there a way to specify endorsement policy using CLI for e.g. during instantiate chaincode

For e.g.

> peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n
>   mycc -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[]}' -P "OutOf(2, 'Org1MSP.peer')"

Comment: So you are trying to set a policy which is more complex than the AND / OR offered by the policy language?

Comment: Just wondering, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Usually if we say de-centralization, more than one peer agree to a transaction. For e.g. say if I have 5 peers, I need to configure that 3 out of 5 peers should endorse a transaction to make it valid. In case of hyperledger looks like for an org only one peer can endorse a transaction.

Comment: Good & detailed approach here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797280/changing-endorsement-policy-to-require-multiple-members-but-not-sure-how-to-get

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the same org twice with an AND:
AND('Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.peer')

Comment: Nope, did not work. Error: Invalid policy AND('Org1MSP.peer','Org1MSP.peer')